# How to pass run time arguments in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gunicorn

I'm trying to dockerize my django project, in order to run the project with gunicorn from the shell I use:

```
gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers $(( 2 * `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core id' | wc -l` + 1 )) MyQ.wsgi:application
```

which works great,
the idea is to utilize as many cores as I can as defined in gunicorn documentation.

the $(( 2 * `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core id' | wc -l` + 1 )) part simply returns 2*n+1 where n is the amount of cores in the system.

However,I'm having some trouble rewriting this command to a Dockerfile, here is my current attempt:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind :8000", "--workers", "$(( 2 * `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core id' | wc -l` + 1 ))", "MyQ.wsgi:application"]
```

This crashes with the following error when I run docker run:

```
gunicorn: error: argument -w/--workers: invalid int value: "$(( 2 * `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core id' | wc -l` + 1 ))"
```

so basically the "$..." is not being evaluated, and I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better to define an Environment Variable with `ENV` instruction in your `Dockerfile` and use that in your `CMD` instruction. This way you can set your Environment Variable when creating a `Container` from your `Docker Image`.

Deifine environment variable like this in your `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV WORKERS 1
```

Then change your `CMD` instruction to this:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers $WORKERS MyQ.wsgi:application"]
```

finally when you are creating the `Container` pass your `WORKERS` environmet variable with `-e` argument.

Comment: can you please show the full flow, the definition in dockerfile and then the usage in the cmd?

Comment: The [official Docker tutorial on custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#dockerfile) has an example of putting an environment variable in a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

There are two forms of the `CMD` (and `ENTRYPOINT` and `RUN`) commands.  The form you wrote is preferred:

```
CMD ["command_name", "--option", "value"]
```

But, it doesn't run a shell to preprocess the command line.  So if you run, for instance,

```
CMD ["ls", ">", "/host/directory/foo.ls"]
```

it will pass `>` as an argument to the program and not do a shell redirect.

So for your construct to work, you need to use the other form, that does implicitly wrap it in a shell execution (`/bin/sh -c '...'`)

```
CMD gunicorn --bind :8000 ...
```

In practice, trying to force runtime constraints like worker count via the Dockerfile isn't what you want; you should allow things like this to be specified in the `docker run` command or similar.  @HassanMusavi's answer is a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile does not support run time arguments(which you want to compute while running docker file). But in your case you can write a script 'test.sh' which has entry for `gunicorn` with the parameters.

And in `CMD` define the script path like `CMD["test.sh"]`. So when you create a container from this image, it will run your script in the container and will evaluate $ expression and get the cores at run time(even though `cat /proc/cpuinfo` will run in your container but it will list down the cores of your docker machine). This way you dont have to depend on calculating cores and passing it as -e.